# Magento: How to remove the price for bundled product options on the shopping cart page, checkout etc

Tags: magento, cart

Please help me removing the price for bundled product options on the shopping cart page, checkout, etc. Here is a pic.

[image]

What do i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this edit:

```
Mage_Bundle_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer
```

Look for the _getBundleOptions() method and at around line 77 change it as follows

```
//$option['value'][] = $this->_getSelectionQty($bundleSelection->getSelectionId()).' x '. $this->htmlEscape($bundleSelection->getName()). ' ' .Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->_getSelectionFinalPrice($bundleSelection));
                        //New line
                        $option['value'][] = $this->_getSelectionQty($bundleSelection->getSelectionId()).' x '. $this->htmlEscape($bundleSelection->getName());
```

Then edit: 
Mage_Bundle_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer 
Look for the getValueHtml() method at around line 115 change the code as follows

```
public function getValueHtml($item)
    {
        if ($attributes = $this->getSelectionAttributes($item)) {
            //Old code
            /*
            return sprintf('%d', $attributes['qty']) . ' x ' .
                $this->htmlEscape($item->getName()) .
                " " . $this->getOrder()->formatPrice($attributes['price']);
             */ 
            return sprintf('%d', $attributes['qty']) . ' x ' .
                $this->htmlEscape($item->getName());
        } else {
            return $this->htmlEscape($item->getName());
        }
    }
```

**The usual caveats about not editing core code and using local or module rewrites apply!**

let me know if i can help you more.

OR Also you can hide with css like below

Assuming that you want to remove it from all items regardless of the price, then you could add this css

```
#shopping-cart-table dd span.price{
    display:none;
}
```

If you only want to remove the price if it is zero,you can also do in this way

```
/app/design/frontend/default/{theme path}/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml (around line # 46)
```

Figure out where it is add the price and only append the price if it is greater than 0
**or**

Do a find a replace str_replace("$0.00", "", $_formatedOptionValue['value']) on the string that display that line (make sure to add the currency sign so that $10.00 dont get replace)

Comment: Hi Liyakat, Thanks for the answer. I looked into **Mage_Bundle_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer** but i couldn't find the line you said. Instead i found this code for _getBundleOptions() `return Mage::helper('bundle/catalog_product_configuration')->getBundleOptions($this->getItem());`

Comment: as with regrad to **Mage_Bundle_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer** I changed the code to what you suggested, but noting happen. Th prices are still there

Comment: Welcome @RaduS pls check my updated answer, and that would be sure will help you..

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to do it. Hopefully it will help somebody.

1 - Go to /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product

2 - open the file Configuration.php

3 - from about line 119 till about 127 you will find this code:

```
           foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {
                $qty = $this->getSelectionQty($product, $bundleSelection->getSelectionId()) * 1;
                if ($qty) {
                    $option['value'][] = $qty . ' x ' . $this->escapeHtml($bundleSelection->getName())
                        . ' ' . Mage::helper('core')->currency(
                            $this->getSelectionFinalPrice($item, $bundleSelection)
                        );
                }
            }
```

Change that with this code:

```
foreach ($bundleSelections as $bundleSelection) {
                    $qty = $this->getSelectionQty($product, $bundleSelection->getSelectionId()) * 1;
                    if ($qty) {
                        $option['value'][] = $this->escapeHtml($bundleSelection->getName());


                    }
                }
```

One caution note, be careful about editing the core file. You can also use local or module rewrites.